# Finding matches of 3 across a html table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML Table:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Im trying to find matches of 3 of the same numbers horizontally or vertically. I want to write a function that checks to see if thier any matches and highlight the cells that have a match for example 333 or 444 etc.

I have started by getting all the td elements in the document putting them in an array:

```
var cellBlocks = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for( i = 0; i < cellBlocks.length; i++){
    console.log("looking for matches");
}
```

I have tried to solve the problem, but don't know where to start.

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/k898mhfy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I converted the table to a two dimensional array to represent the grid. Each item is an object which contains the cells. I do this by getting all the rows and then for each row getting all the cells;

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var matchAim = 3;

var data = [];

for( var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
    var rowData = [];
    var cellBlocks = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

    for( var j = 0; j < cellBlocks.length; j++){
        var cellBlock = cellBlocks[j];
        rowData.push(cellBlock);
    }

    data.push(rowData);
}
```

I then use this array to check for matches. I created a function `checkForMatches` which checks for matches either horizontally or vertically. When a match is found the `changeColorForMatch` function loops through the array and changes the color for the cells:

```
function checkForMatches(isHorizontal) {
    console.debug('Checking matches ' + (isHorizontal ? 'horizontally' : 'vertically'));
    for (var k = 0; k < data[0].length; k++) {
        var currentNumber;
        var matchCount = 1;

        for (var l = 0; l < data.length; l++) {
            var cellBlock = isHorizontal ? data[k][l] : data[l][k];
            var cellNumber = cellBlock.innerText;
            if (!currentNumber || currentNumber !== cellNumber) {
                if (matchCount >= matchAim) {
                    var horizontalIndex = isHorizontal ? l: k;
                    var verticalIndex = isHorizontal ? k : l
                    changeColorForMatch(matchCount, isHorizontal, horizontalIndex, verticalIndex);
                }

                currentNumber = cellNumber;
                matchCount = 1;
            }
            else {
                matchCount++;
            }
        }

        if (matchCount >= matchAim) {
            var horizontalIndex = isHorizontal ? data.length: k;
            var verticalIndex = isHorizontal ? k : data.length;
            changeColorForMatch(matchCount, isHorizontal, horizontalIndex, verticalIndex);
        }
    }
}

function changeColorForMatch(matchCount, isHorizontal, horizontalIndex, verticalIndex) {

    for (var i = matchCount; i > 0; i--) {
        var cellBlock = isHorizontal ? data[verticalIndex][horizontalIndex - i] : data[verticalIndex - i][horizontalIndex];

        cellBlock.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}
```

I then call `checkForMatches` for both horizontally and vertically.

Given some more time I'm sure I could improve the code a bit more to make it a little cleaner but the code is functional. It assumes that the table has the same width as height.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7mf182gw/2/

Answer (score 1):

One id tag is necessary on the table. Use something like the following:

```
  var table = document.getElementById("the_table"), row, cell, content;
  for (var j=0;j<table.rows.length;j++) {
    row = table.rows[j];
    for (i=0;i<row.cells.length;i++) {
       cell = row.cells[i];
       content = cell.innerHTML;
       do whatever
    }
  }
```

You can also use  table.rows[zz].cells[ww].innerHTML  as an array. If other elements are in the cell you will need to use childNodes.